# Sliding down a hidden text with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slide

I'm trying to make a box that, when clicked, show some text on it.
Very simple, and it works, but I can't make the text appear by sliding; when I try that, it is displayed in a weird animation, with almost none sliding at all.

I made a JSFiddle version with new code, that worked almost perfectly (the only problem there is the delay right before the text sliding, **I wish it could be more softly animated**), but I don't know what I've done differently in my real version, so I've put it on JSFiddle too, so **you can compare**.

The test version:
https://jsfiddle.net/5dfazgyw/6/

The real code based version:
https://jsfiddle.net/188qgqjL/5/
(note that it only slides in the beginning of the animation, after that it appears spontaneously)

I'm putting my test version here, but the one that matters the most is the real code version:

```js
$('tr').on('click', function() {
 $('#table tr td p2').slideToggle()
})
```

```css
td {
  width:350px;
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  padding:30px;
  cursor:default;
}

td p {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

td p2 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">

<tr><td>
<p>
LOREM IPSUM
</p>
<p2>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
</p2>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<p>
LOREM IPSUM
</p>
<p2>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
</p2>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<p>
LOREM IPSUM
</p>
<p2>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
</p2>
</td></tr>

</table>
```

I'm really trying to make this works, but I can't reach the effect I want.

Comment: `<p2>` is **invalid HTML**. there is no `p2`element in *any* HTML version.

Comment: @connexo, do you think it can affect the sliding? I didn't know that, using p2 or p4 have always worked for me like an actual HTML tag haha

Comment: That might a) not be the case in browser you haven't tested in, and b) change at any given point in the future when a browser vendor decides to stop ignoring errors like yours. I'm unwilling to even look at any other problems in code if stuff like that isn't fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

See this example

```js
$('tr').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find("p2").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 350px;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: default;
}

td p {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

td p2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        LOREM IPSUM
      </p>
      <p2>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      </p2>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        LOREM IPSUM
      </p>
      <p2>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      </p2>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        LOREM IPSUM
      </p>
      <p2>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      </p2>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This fails to mention that OP uses invalid HTML. Also, jQuery features chaining, so `$(this).find("p2").slideToggle()` would be more concise than introducing an otherwise useless variable.

Comment: @connexo as you like.

Comment: I'm using .find() in the version that's based in the actual code (https://jsfiddle.net/188qgqjL/5/), but it does not solve my sliding issue...